# Traversing the linked list once to remove & Insert the same Node

Tags: node.js, data-structures, asymptotic-complexity

Assume we have a LinkedList of Objects that is structured based on some specific criteria that are nonrelevant, the List can get very very very long so doing anything other than a single traversal is somewhat unattainable. We would like to remove our Node from somewhere to the right of the least (near the tail ) and insert it to somewhere in the middle or to the left of the list. 
The real problem is that we don't have an idea of where we have to remove the node from and where we have to insert the removed node into. We just know that we will insert the Node to the left of where it was before and it may be many Nodes before where it was previously.

I am trying to do this as fast as possible in terms of the number of operations.Any suggestions?

Comment: Go from right to left.

Comment: @John, how do you go right to left unless it's a double linked list?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach: Obviously it would have to be a double linked list.  OP didn't specify single or double.  If it's currently single, make it double.

Comment: If the list has to be single for some reason, it could also just be reversed so the scan is still from head to tail but the data is in the required order.

Answer (score 0):

As @John Zwinck said, you can use a doubly linked list to go from right to left in the linked list.

There is one more solution that you can look into. You can break the linked list into smaller lists and use different processes/threads to check each one of them. This solution would of course be more complicated to execute and it depends on how important these operations are to you and your team regarding the time and space complexity.